# Android: Make image fullscreen on touch

Tags: android, zooming

I'm displaying many images in my app between the text.

I want to make the image zoom to fullscreen on touch. I don't know how to do that. I also searched a lot.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: you want to pinch in to zoom?

Comment: try this https://github.com/jasonpolites/gesture-imageview

Comment: pass that image to new activity with intents and show it in an ImageView having height and width as match_parent.

Comment: you can also use this.http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2013/04/update-pinch-to-zoom-example-and.html

Answer (score 0):

Convert Bitmap to Byte array

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

Pass it to next activity with the use of intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("picture", byteArray);
startActivity(intent);
```

Get Byte Array from Bundle and Convert into Bitmap Image:-

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
byte[] byteArray = extras.getByteArray("picture");

Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Just make sure that `ImageView` has width and height as `match_parent`